Creating a list of dictionaries from pandas dataframe for scatter plot
I have a dataframe like this:
data = [['value', 'Jan'], ['value', 'Feb'], ['value', 'Mar'], ['value', 'Apr'], ['value', 'Mag'], ['value', 'Jun']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value', 'month'])

From the dataframe above I want to create a list of dictionaries exactly like this:
custom_labels = [
 {'value': 'Jan'},
 {'value': 'Feb'},
 {'value': 'Mar'},
 {'value': 'Apr'},
 {'value': 'May'},
 {'value': 'Jun'},]

I need this list of dictionaries beacuse i need to pass the categories of data labels to a scatter plot from a data contained in a dataframe (custom data labels peculiarity of xlxswriter)
Link to custom data labels

Unfortunately, this isn't one of the types of output that DataFrame.to_dict() can generate. I think you'll have to write your own function for it.

Is value always that string, or is that a placeholder for some variable set of values?

Just zip the two columns and use a short list comprehension:
out = [dict([x]) for x in zip(df['value'], df['month'])]

Or, mostly for fun, using numpy to reshape:
out = list(map(dict, df[['value', 'month']].values[:, None]))

Output:
[{'value': 'Jan'},
 {'value': 'Feb'},
 {'value': 'Mar'},
 {'value': 'Apr'},
 {'value': 'Mag'},
 {'value': 'Jun'}]


I'm surprised no body recommended iterrows yet:
[{x: y} for _, (x, y) in df.iterrows()]

Output:
[{'value': 'Jan'},
 {'value': 'Feb'},
 {'value': 'Mar'},
 {'value': 'Apr'},
 {'value': 'Mag'},
 {'value': 'Jun'}]


One option is to only pull the month column, rename to value and use to_dict():
 dict = df[['month']].rename(columns={"month": "value"}).to_dict(orient='records')


You can use to_dict and a list comprehension:
custom_labels = [{d[0]: d[1]} for d in df.to_dict('tight').get('data')]

[{'value': 'Jan'}, {'value': 'Feb'}, {'value': 'Mar'}, {'value': 'Apr'}, {'value': 'Mag'}, {'value': 'Jun'}]

